# Rememberable in Devise Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, session-cookies, remember-me

I have seen a few posts about this but none that truly seem to answer what I'd like to understand which is – "How do I know rememberable is working the way I think it should be?"

While testing in localhost using the EditThisCookie chrome extension, I am able to see that a remember_user_token is being created but how do I know before pushing this to staging that it's working correctly?

Maybe I'm being a little too broad for the likings for stackoverflow but I didn't want to make this into a long-winded post where I post my code and ask someone to dissect it – that's not my intention. More than anything, I'm looking for some guidelines maybe even a great blog post/tutorial that explains setting this up step-by-step so I can wrap my head around if it's working and the how/why behind it. Thanks in advance and I apologize if my approach was not the best. I'd be happy to provide more information for some feedback/maybe tips to consider that I didn't consider previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tests within the devise gem that ensure the `rememberable` is working as expected. You can read at them here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/integration/rememberable_test.rb

Let me know if I'm missing some part of the question :)